# Geonames bounding box

Tags: python, geonames

I use geonames API to validate whether a "string" is a place/location. The following is a snippet of my code.

```
import geonames.adapters.search

sa = geonames.adapters.search.Search(my_user_name)
result = sa.query('bordeaux').east_west_north_south_box([141.021805, 95.009331, 5.904417, -10.941861]).execute()

theresult = set()
for id_, name in result.get_flat_results():
    theresult.add(name.lower())
print 'bordeaux' in theresult
```

As you can see I added a bounding box of Indonesia when I did the search. But to my surprise the result of this code is "True" where we all know that Bordeaux is located in France. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried printing result and theresult to see if there is a reason for what you are seeing?

Comment: Yes, in theresult there is a "Bordeaux" entry. I mean that is the weird thing. It shouldn't be there in the first place because I put a boundary box of Indonesia. My understanding is that anything showing up in theresult should be a place in the boundary of Indonesia. Clearly, in Indonesia we do not have a location called Bordeaux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using coordinates bounding box use the country code, for example:

```
result = sa.query('bordeaux').country('id').execute()
```

returns no results, whereas:

```
result = sa.query('jakarta').country('id').execute()
```

returns some appropriate results, as does:

```
result = sa.query('bordeaux').country('fr').execute()
```

and also:

```
result = sa.query('bordeaux').country('us').execute()
```

**Update:**

Did some research and the geonames_rdf library doesn't convert the bounding box parameter into HTTP/REST parameters correctly - it applies a single parameter "east,west,south,north" when they should all be separate values.

To fix this, in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\geonames\adapters\base.py, change:

```
def east_west_north_south_box(self, value):
    return self.set_string_parameter('east,west,north,south', value)
```

to (works for my simple testing):

```
def east_west_north_south_box(self, value):
    for coord,val in zip(['east','west','north','south'],value):
        self.set_string_parameter(coord, val)
    return self
```

Personally, using the country name seems preferable to the rather crude bounding box.

Comment: I already tried using the country code and it worked. But I also received some weird results, for example: "los", "warung", etc. That is why I want to specify a bounding box so only locations which are in the box will be returned. By the way, your answer on the bounding box is working perfectly. Thank you.